# I want to use JavaScript to control office online server page turning of PowerPoint, but I can't find any relevant documents

Tags: ms-wopi, office-online-server, microsoft-document-viewer

I want to use JavaScript to control the last page, the next page, the full screen of **PowerPoint**. I looked at the **PostMessage**, but there were no such actions

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you are trying to do and what "page turning of PowerPoint" really means.

Comment: @DaliborGrudenic I want to use JavaScript to control the last page, the next page, the full screen of PowerPoint. I looked at the PostMessage, but there were no such actions.

Comment: Can you add this description to original question and also tag question with office-js

Answer (score 0):

You can't use javascript "directly" you have to call these actions through Microsoft javascript API. You will need to build PowerPoint add-in by using [Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) platform. There are some nice tutorials for PowerPoint [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins-get-started?tabs=visual-studio-code) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/powerpoint-tutorial-navigate-slides) that you can follow and that will give you an idea of what can be done by building PowerPoint add-in. I would suggest you get familiar with the technology and concepts before moving to tutorials. Also note that [PowerPoint API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/powerpoint-and-project-note) is not fully developed and there are some features missing but you might not need them. There is [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33200554-powerpoint-api) page where you can register and up vote for different office-js API features so it gets Microsoft office-js team attention.

Comment: I just need control when previewing online through office online server. And this PowerPoint is read-only.

Comment: I got that part but to best to my knowledge you'll not be able to do it with PostMessage because there is nothing there listening for your messages.